# Integration by Parametric Integration.

Tags: integration

I have a question that I have no idea how to start:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x-1}{\ln x}dx$$

So in one of my classes, I learned a technique called parametric integration. But I have no idea how to use the technique with this question.

Any hints/help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parametric integrand you want is as follows. Put

$$f(p)=\int_0^1\frac{x^p-1}{\ln x}dx$$

Then

$$f'(p) =\int_0^1\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\left(\frac{x^p-1}{\ln x}\right)dx=\int_0^1 x^p\;dx=\left.\frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1}\right|_0^1=\dfrac{1}{p+1}$$

so $f(p)= \ln(p+1)+ C$, where $C$ is to be determined. To find $C$, just note that $f(0)=0$ since the integrand vanishes when $p=0$; this means $C=0$, so
$$f(p)=\ln(p+1).$$

*Note:* In your specific case, take $p=1$ to get
$\int_0^1\frac{x-1}{\ln x}dx=\boxed{\ln 2}.$

Comment: Great solution, definitely what I was looking for!

Comment: Note I corrected a typo. I had $\ln p$ instead of $\ln x$ originally. All better now.

Comment: Had a question. When you differentiate with respect to p. Don't you get $x^p - 1$?

Comment: No, $\frac{1}{\ln x}$ is constant w.r.t. $p$, right?

Comment: Woops. I see it. Just a silly mistake. :P Thanks again!